# Character sequence sent through send_keys() geting concatenated with the default text present through Python and Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have following field:

```
<input name="accountId" required="" type="text" id="accountId" class="active form-control" value="90646301">
```

I am trying to clear the value before sending keys:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_name('accountId').clear()
self.driver.find_element_by_name('accountId').send_keys("123455")
```

When my test is run, it enters `90646301123455` in the "Account" field. In other words, it concatenates the value and my string.

How can I only enter the string I pass?

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have shared you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

```
myInput = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.active.form-control#accountId")))
# or
myInput = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='active form-control' and @id='accountId']")))
myInput.click()
myInput.clear()
myInput.send_keys('12345')
```

Alternatively, you can also use `execute_script()` method as follows:

```
myInput = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.active.form-control#accountId")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('value')", myInput);
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','123455')", myInput);
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```